# I have checked 5 checkboxes, and 2 are unchecked. But all get sent. How can I prevent sending unchecked values?

Tags: javascript

I am select 5 checked on checkbox and  2 replace with unchecked but all value are submitted how can i am stop to submitting unchecked value..??

```
function checkSelected(obj)
{
    var recObj = "rec" + obj;

    if(eval("document.frm2."+recObj+".checked"))
    {

        var val=document.getElementById("listCount").value;

        var len=val++;
        document.getElementById("listCount").value=len;

        var value=document.getElementById(recObj).value;

        // var arr = [];
        // arr.push(value);
        // document.getElementById("srNoValue").value=arr;
        var SerNO="";
        if(document.getElementById("srNoValue").value !=''){
            SerNO=document.getElementById("srNoValue").value;
            SerNO=SerNO+','+value;
            document.getElementById("srNoValue").value=SerNO;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("srNoValue").value=value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("value is coming");
        document.frm2.listCount.value--;
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone will understand the meaning of this line then please share with me.. Thanx and op please careful with english.

Comment: if(eval("document.frm2."+recObj+".checked")) ??, -> document.frm2[recObj].checked work perfectly, no need for eval. @Leothelion I think OP problem is that the form is submitting checkbox value either they are checked or not. We need to see your html and how your form is submitted ot be abble to answer